# .net windows service local application data is different then in normal app

Tags: c#, windows-services

In normal console app I have this

Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData is `C:\Users\Simon\AppData\Local\`

In Windows service

`Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData` is `C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\`

How can I specify same path in both type of application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that the services run under a different user profile (can be a LOCAL_SERVICE, NETWORK_SERVICE, etc.) If you'd like them to be the same, run the service under your user profile (You can specify this ServiceProcessInstaller.Account property when you create the installer, or in the Services manager of windows).

Comment: Thank you. So what is best solution? I have WS and its manager. Both need to access to settings file. Should I use CommonApplicationData special folder instead? Or should I try ServiceProcessInstaller.Account property? My app will run on lots of different PC's and accounts...

Comment: Is this an application that could be run as either a windows service or a desktop application? You may want to look in to `IsolatedStorage` as it uses the assembly name to store the information, just depends if other applications would need to access it as well.

Comment: Application has two parts, first is Windows Service, for long time run, even if user is not logged. Second part is "Settings Manager". This is desktop app used to config first part - WS. Both parts need to access same settings xml file.

Comment: You can add a manifest to the service to run under administrator and keep the settings file in the install path. (\program files\MyService\service.exe & config.xml) From there, presuming the windows application resides in the same folder  as the service install path (\program files\MyService\settings_manager.exe), you can make the "Settings" application require admin also when it wants to make modifications it can. This will allow both win vista/7 machines and older OSes alike permission to make settings changes.

Comment: If it does work, please let me know. Though I've never run in to needing to do this, I'd be curious as to how it plays out or if you had to take another route.

Comment: I have problem how to determine program files folder in WS. this Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() points to C:\Windows\system32. Other thing is that I need to load some settings for logger and path is relative (in same folder is xml and logger ddl).

Comment: Thank you. It works great. I have win service, it writes to programe files without problems. At start of win service I used Directory.SetCurrentDirectory()

Comment: As an aside, Windows Services have a method `OnCustomCommand(int command)` you can use to notify the service there have been settings file changes and it needs to reload (just point to ponder). Also, if this answer was acceptable don't forget to mark it as such. ;-)

Comment: Interesting point! I'll take a look on it. Answer is accepted, thank you very much.

Comment: BTW, if your service's executable is 32-bit on a 64-bit OS then the folder is C:\Windows\sysWOW64\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local.