# NLog with two running programs

Tags: c#, nuget, nlog, nlog.config

I´ve got a Windows-Service which runs in the same location as its Notify. They communicate with [WebSocketSharp](https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp).

But only one program has a log file. I think the problem is, the notify consumes the `nlog.config` at first and for the service the `nlog.config` is locked. But I may confuse it. Also always the Notify only produces the log, never the service. May be in my `nlog.config` is an error? But then why does the notify produce one but the Service not, when the service and the notify should use the same?

I've tested and the service does not produce any log, even the notify is not running.

May there be a problem with Windows Service and NLog?

Here my `NLog.config`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <time type="AccurateUtc" />
   <targets>
      <target name="debug-logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="${specialfolder:folder=ApplicationData}/MyService/log/${date:format=yyyy-MM}.log" layout="${longdate} | ${level} | ${message}" />
      <target name="trace-logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="${specialfolder:folder=ApplicationData}/MyService/log/trace/${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd}.log" layout="${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd HH\:mm\:ss.fffffff} | ${level} | ${message}" />
      <target name="errorfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="${specialfolder:folder=ApplicationData}/MyService/log/Error.log" layout="${longdate} | ${level} | ${message}" />
      <target name="console" xsi:type="Console" layout="${longdate} | ${level} | ${callsite} | ${message}" />
   </targets>
   <rules>
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="trace-logfile" />
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="debug-logfile" />
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="errorfile" />
   </rules>
</nlog>
```

Here is how I use NLog:

```cs
protected static NLog.Logger Log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
Log.Trace("Message");
```

Comment: Could it be to do with this? [windows service local application data is different then in normal app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247581/net-windows-service-local-application-data-is-different-then-in-normal-app)

Comment: What happens if you use `${specialfolder:folder=CommonApplicationData}` ? See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Special-Folder-Layout-Renderer